# Using iOS device as a remote shutter for a second iOS device

Tags: ios, objective-c, bluetooth

I am trying to create an iOS device that will connect to another iOS device via BLE that will let me take a picture remotely. I would like to use the default camera app on the 2nd device.

I've done a bit of research on similar hardware devices such as Bluetooth selfie sticks, and it seems that they send key events like "volume up" to trigger the action. I have no experience with Bluetooth, and I could not find any resources that helped with my specific problem.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: What you are trying to do is not possible.